# photoshop script: forced UI update

Tags: user-interface, updates, flash-cs5, photoshop-script, adobe-scriptui

I have got my script to work and I just want to add a progressbar to show the progress (duh!).
This is a test script I made because I discovered the problem in my original script. In the original script there is a lot of opening,saving,copy,paste and transformations in the loop...

```
var StatusWindow = new Window("window","Production");

StatusWindow.size = [400,150];
StatusWindow.alignChildren = "left";
StatusWindow.TextProgress = StatusWindow.add("statictext",[0,0,200,0]);
StatusWindow.BarProgress = StatusWindow.add("progressbar",[0,0,200,12]);
StatusWindow.show();

for (n=0; n<100; n++) {
  StatusWindow.TextProgress.text = n;
  StatusWindow.BarProgress.value = n;
  $.sleep(100);
}
alert("Done!);
```

The script runs and shows the Window and the progressbar. Then nothing is updated in the UI until the alert box shows up. If I pause the script (whitin ExtendScript Toolkit CS5), the UI is updated with thext and correct progress. I know that an UI normaly only get updated when there is time "left over" in the system, but this is ridiculous!!!

How can I force Photoshop to update the UI when I want it too?

//Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(From the [JavaScript Tools guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf)) You can use StatusWindow.update()

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using app.refresh() or waitForRedraw(). The window.update() did not seem to solve this problem for me.

Here is the source: http://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/scriptui-window-in-photoshop-palette-vs-dialog/